# Data in array does not come out the same

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I create. When reading the array with `print_r` it is not returning with the correct data inputted! I am missing specific sectionsn such as `< & >` brackets with its headings.

How can i preserve these?

Code:

```
$params = array(
    "Parm1" => "test",
    "Parm2" => "hi",
    "Parm3" => GUID(),
    "Parm4" => "lol",
    "Parm5" => "
    <R>
      <R1>the</R1>
      <R2>dog</R2>
      <R3>is</R3>

      <R15>happy</R15>

      <R20>today</R20>
    </R>
");
```

Basically the only data that is jumbled up is the `Parm5` section. I want everything inside to return exactly as it is! EG: Reading as is i only receive `Array ( [Parm1] => test [Parm2] => hi [Parm3] => B18BE727-8F79-4D4A-80EA-3974B1429F78 [Parm4] => lol [Parm5] => the dog is happy today )` from `print_r`

I want to return:

`Array ( [Parm1] => test [Parm2] => hi [Parm3] => B18BE727-8F79-4D4A-80EA-3974B1429F78 [Parm4] => lol [Parm5] => <R><R1>the</R1> <R2>dog</R2> <R3>is</R3> <R15>happy</R15> <R20>today</R20></R> )`

Comment: It's working fine: https://eval.in/1034236. Are you sure that your browser isn't trying to render `<R15></R15>` as HTML? What happens if you `print_r` inside a `pre` element?

Comment: Yeah it was rendering as HTML! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

escape `param5` with `htmlspecialchars('<R> ..... </R>')`. Your browser currently sees it as html tags and parses it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars` on the return value of `print_r`:

```
echo "<pre>";    
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($params, true));
echo "</pre>";
```